# Trouble Creating a Treemap with D3.js (Fetch API cannot load)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, data-science

I am trying to reproduce this d3.js Treemap plot below and my browser is showing a blank.

https://bl.ocks.org/d3indepth/502c024a398dc772fe947905f217dab3

I copy pasted the information in the csv file and saved it as a csv. Then I copied the HTML exactly from index.html. I then changed the below line from the html file

from `<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>` into

`<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>`

I end up running into this error on the Chrome console in inspect element.

`d3.min.js:2 Fetch API cannot load ~directory/films.csv. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request`

And now I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated, as this is my first time working with Javascript.

Comment: do you have a local http server running? Have you also convert to using Promises?

Comment: no local http server running. is that strictly necessary? and am not familiar with promises, so i guess not? i literally just copy pasted the code

Comment: d3v5 has changed to use promises and it will not work with "local files", you have to load them from an HTTP connection (a web browser is not allowed to get local files by requests)